# Is it possible to delete an entry from a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to delete an entry from a JavaScript array? The entry in the list gets replaced with null when delete operator is used.

```
data = [{pid:30, pname:abc}, {pid:31, pname:def}, {pid:32, pname:zxc}]
delete data[1]
```

becomes:

```
data = [{pid:30, pname:abc}, null, {pid:32, pname:zxc}]
```

FYI I'm getting this as json back from an ajax call. The returned value is parsed like `var data = YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(result.value || '[]')`

Comment: what language are you working in?

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, JSON refers to the actual String value returned by a JSON stringifier. It looks like you are actually talking about a JavaScript literal expression, which looks like JSON  but is actually JS code.

Comment: oh sorry should have mentioned its javascript.

Comment: its javascript and json is returned from an ajax call to php. the returned value is parsed like var data = YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(result.value || '[]');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about sort()ing and then splice()ing the list?

Comment: To cellect all the nulls together and splice them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

There are many librarys out there that deal with the serialization and deserialzation of JSON content. Many of those librarys also allow you to manipulate the data from JSON also.

Depending on what language you're using will determine which library you decide to use.

More details would be helpful.

Comment: its javascript and json is returned from an ajax call to php. the returned value is parsed like

var data = YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(result.value || '[]');

Comment: FYI I updated the question to include the specific JavaScript context the OP is in.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the JavaScript Array class. Deleting a value always leaves a hole. You need to create a new array without the hole. Something like this might be helpful:

```
    Array.prototype.removeItem = function(index){
        var newArray = []
        for (var i =0; i < this.length; ++i){
            if (i==index||typeof this[i] === "undefined") continue;
            newArray.push(this[i]);
        }
        return newArray;
    }

    var a1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    delete a1[1]
    alert(a1.join())
    //prints 1,,3,4,5

    var a2 = a1.removeItem(3)
    alert(a2.join())
    //prints 1,3,5 -- removed item 3 and previously "deleted" item 1
```